# How do I get the password to upload keystore file (keystore password incorrect)

Tags: android, react-native, keystore, android-keystore

I have an issue where the previous developer isn't totally cooperative. As he refused to share the keystore file password and he claims the password is in the file. when I checked  the gradle.properties file the password was there but when i try to assemblebuild release (aab file).

I get incorrect password error,
[image]

Am Open to any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload keys are just for uploading the app to Google. You can at any time create a new upload key and register it in the used Google developer account used to publish the app.

See also https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/community-guide/243925915/how-to-request-a-new-upload-key?hl=en

> If you are unable to sign your app because you have forgotten your key password or lost the keystore file then your only option is to reset your upload key.

Comment: Thanks...

So, I will need to create a new upload key file. Which means there's no way to retrieve

Comment: @yusufff You just need the password to access the keystore. That is security provided by cryptography. If there would be a way to bypass the password the password would become meaningless.

Comment: Make sense, thank God there's nothing like that for iOS